# Magento 1.7 api - proxy.catalogcategorycreate() throwing error

Tags: c#, magento

while i'm trying to create category in magento using api. it throws error for each category
using code.

```
categoryEntity = new catalogCategoryEntityCreate();

string[] sortby_values;
    sortby_values = cat.available_sort_by.ToString().Split(',');
    currstore = 1;
//string[] sortby = new[] { "name", "price" };
string[] sortby;
sortby = sortby_values;// new[] { "name", "price" };
categoryEntity.available_sort_by = sortby;
rtbState.Text += "testing";
categoryEntity.default_sort_by = cat.default_sort_by; // "name";
//categoryEntity.available_sort_by = null;
//categoryEntity.default_sort_by = null;
categoryEntity.description = null;
categoryEntity.is_active =                           Convert.ToInt16(rectify_option(cat.is_active.ToString()));
categoryEntity.is_activeSpecified = cat.is_activeSpecified;
categoryEntity.include_in_menu = Convert.ToInt16(rectify_option(cat.include_in_menu.ToString()));
categoryEntity.include_in_menuSpecified = cat.include_in_menuSpecified;
categoryEntity.name = cat.Name;
WriteLine("Category with code : " + categoryEntity.name + " Created in magento Successfully.");
if (cat.Is_Anchor == Is_Anchor.Yes)
    categoryEntity.is_anchor = 1;
else
    categoryEntity.is_anchor = 0;
categoryEntity.is_anchorSpecified = true;
try
{   
    int categoryid = proxy.catalogCategoryCreate(sessionId, cat.parent_category_id , categoryEntity, "1" );
}
```

it throws error at this last line. The error is: **Call to a member function getId() on a non-object**

Answer (score 0):

it's problem in magento 1.7.0.3.
you have to change one setting.
admin/system/configuration/extensions/dropdownmenu
make it disabled (field name enabled) dropdown and make it disabled.
now use api and create category successfully..